# Does the current ban on evictions apply to expiring leases?

Tags: united-states, california, covid-19

My friend is currently in a pickle. Their lease expires in a couple of weeks and they were originally planning to move to a different property. However given the lockdown in California, moving is no longer allowed as it is not an "essential" activity, so it is impossible for them to arrange a moving truck.

Given the situation, would the ban on evictions apply once the lease is expired?

Comment: Are you talking about [Executive Order N-28-20 of March 16](https://www.gov.ca.gov/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/3.16.20-Executive-Order.pdf)?  First, it doesn't actually ban any evictions by itself, but allows local governments to do so, so we'd need to know where your friend is located.  Second, note paragraph 2 (I can't copy and paste).  It limits the effect to evictions arising out of rent nonpayment due to decrease in income, which does not seem to be your friend's situation.

Comment: @NateEldredge San Francisco. But if you're not allowed to move, what are you supposed to do?

Comment: Not a law-based answer (and hence a comment):  Offer to extend the lease by a month or two.  If the landlord hasn't arranged new tenants yet, then that's extra income they were unlikely to otherwise get (nobody's going to sign a new lease just now).  And if the landlord has arranged new tenants, those new tenants are unlikely to be able to move in for the same reason, in which case your friend wouldn't be displacing anyone who has a right to the apartment.  Both of the above tactics, though, hinge on the landlord and the new tenants being reasonable people.

Answer (score 2):

I expect there to be some "clarifications" of [the order](https://www.gov.ca.gov/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/3.19.20-attested-EO-N-33-20-COVID-19-HEALTH-ORDER.pdf), which orders all residents of California to stay home and does few exceptions. There is an exception for people doing to work in "16 critical infrastructure areas", but no exception that allows you to go to the grocery store. However, it later says that "when people need to leave their mores or places of residence to obtain or perform the functions above, or to otherwise facilitate authorized necessary activities, they should at all times practice social distancing". This suggests that it actually is legal to go to the grocery store, sinece "food" is one of [the 16 areas](https://www.cisa.gov/identifying-critical-infrastructure-during-covid-19). There may also be separate decrees authorizing buying food, perhaps buying home-repair materials, and so on. In comparison, the Santa Clara lockdown decree was more explicit, and included "whatever you have to do to eat, be sheltered, get cured....". I think it is not entirely determined that moving is a non-essential activity.

To evict a person for staying past the end of the lease, the landlord would have to get a court order. But the courts will not order a tenant to move, if moving is illegal.